# Android View Layout Scaling bitmaps

Tags: android, layout, android-layout

I'm working an a layout which I will have a bitmap centered, and I'd like the left & right margin bitmaps to scale (horizontally) to fill the screen, such that my center item can be a decorated titlebar, and the left & right are filler bitmaps that match the center bitmaps background, and thus stretching horizontally.

But what I'm seeing is there is a space between the bitmaps. The left & right scale, but there is a space between them.

Eg what I'm getting is:
http://www.58seconds.com/getting.png

What I want is:
http://www.58seconds.com/want.png

Any ideas?

Here is a snippet of the Layout code I use:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >   
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="45sp"
    android:src="@drawable/mdjleftfiller"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="top" 
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/command_selection_topImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45sp"
    android:src="@drawable/top_image"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="top" 
    android:layout_weight="0"
    />
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="45sp"
    android:src="@drawable/mdjrightfiller"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="top" 
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about creating a 9-patch with your single title bar image? If you have your "stretched" parts on either side of the actual title it will stretch to fit whatever you want without resorting to layout trickery.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating two images, one as a background and scaleType to FIT_CENTER, then set the other one to lay on top and just move to the center.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice clean way of doing this, that is pretty much exactly what Lucas was talking about, but in xml:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/navbar" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"           android:background="@drawable/titlebar_repeat">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/titlebar_logo" android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

In this case titlebar_repeat is just a single pixel wide, and titlebar_logo is just the text with a transparent background.  In your case, since you don't seem to want highly stylized text, you could probably just make the ImageView a TextView instead if you like.